# After I got span index, how do I highlight the selected span and print the selected text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used that code to get the index of a span and i want to highlight the selected span and print the selected text.

```js
let
    div = document.querySelector('div'),
    text = div.innerText;
div.addEventListener('mouseup', evt => {
    let
        sel = getSelection(),
        result = {
            start: null,
            end: null
        };
    ['start', 'end'].forEach(which => {
        let
            counter = 1,
            tmpNode = div.querySelector('span'),
            node = which == 'start' ? 'anchor' : 'focus';
        if (!sel) return;
        while (tmpNode !== sel[node + 'Node'].parentElement) {
            result[which] += tmpNode.innerText.length;
            counter++;
            tmpNode = div.querySelector('span:nth-child(' + counter + ')')
        }
        result[which] += sel[node + 'Offset'] + (which == 'start' ? 1 : 0);
    });
    alert('Selection starts at ' + result.start + ' and ends at ' + result.end);
}, false);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>plain </span>
  <span>text </span>
  <span>and </span>
  <span>this </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>more </span>
  <span>plain </span>
  <span>text </span>
  <span>and </span>
  <span>this </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>the </span>
  <span>final </span>
  <span>plain </span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

I am using the previous code to highlight for admin panel to review and compare between to texts and highlight the wrong words.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing . you need to send the selected text into a popup or an iframe and print that document.  print() will print the whole current document and eventually use the @print media style sheet. I would use the iframe method.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus if you now what the question is, can you please edit the question so that there is a question?

Comment: @Natrium , maybe you should ask the op to clarify what he wants to do next when he is able to print that text. . For what i understand, he only tells that he uses the code to compare highlighted text  with another one withouth saying that he has an issue there *(maybe clumsy,  that should not have been said that way)* ,  but printing as stated in the title . there was no php tag to mistake with  *print * meaning.  Also, to  *highlight span* do not seem to be a clear  issue , unless he wanted too  to modyfy colors of selection. However, printing partially a document is not possible via print()

Comment: @G-Cyrillus CSI Stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I used that code to get the index of a span and i want to highlight the selected span and print the selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663093/i-used-that-code-to-get-the-index-of-a-span-and-i-want-to-highlight-the-selected)

Answer (score 0):

Possible example from my comment using an iframe to create a standalone document from the selection (or string)  to print:

```js
let div = document.querySelector("div"),
  text = div.innerText;
div.addEventListener(
  "mouseup",
  evt => {
    let sel = getSelection(),
      result = {
        start: null,
        end: null
      };
    ["start", "end"].forEach(which => {
      let counter = 1,
        tmpNode = div.querySelector("span"),
        node = which == "start" ? "anchor" : "focus";
      if (!sel) return;
      while (tmpNode !== sel[node + "Node"].parentElement) {
        result[which] += tmpNode.innerText.length;
        counter++;
        tmpNode = div.querySelector("span:nth-child(" + counter + ")");
      }
      result[which] += sel[node + "Offset"] + (which == "start" ? 1 : 0);
    });
    //alert('Selection starts at '+result.start+' and ends at '+result.end);
    printMyFrame(sel);
  },
  false
);

function printMyFrame(sel) {
  var printFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  printFrame.setAttribute("id", "iframe");
  printFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  // printFrame.style.opacity = "0"; // uncomment to hide it
  document.body.appendChild(printFrame);
  var doc = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write(sel);
  doc.close();
  printFrame.onload = printFrame.contentWindow.print();
  printFrame.contentWindow.onafterprint = document.body.removeChild(printFrame);
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>This </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>plain </span>
  <span>text </span>
  <span>and </span>
  <span>this </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>more </span>
  <span>plain </span>
  <span>text </span>
  <span>and </span>
  <span>this </span>
  <span>is </span>
  <span>the </span>
  <span>final </span>
  <span>plain </span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

demo online https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rNVdwrP

cross-origin security can be an issue.